# How to learn about memristors as a circuit designer?

Tags: simulation, modeling, device

I'm trying to learn about memristors to play with it in circuit design. I think it might be more intuitive to do tests and measurements rather than reading maths formulas. The problem is that I don't have a physical memristor, and the so-called models I found in literatures were not agreeing with each other (In other words, I don't know which is better, and all of them are complicated. Some of them even has bugs). Is there a recognised good model with high accuracy (like BSIM4 for MOSFETs)?

The other problem is that I have yet to find intuitive and in-depth materials for circuit designers. I guess as a circuit designer, we don't have to understand the meaning of thousands of parameters, but we need an intuitive and easy model (eg. consider MOSFET to be VCCS). Is there any books/papers/tutorials providing such an explanation, and can be helpful to design circuit with memristors?

Comment: There isn't much accessible literature on memristors because no one has made a memristor commercially available. Some have been made in the lab (and not that many, either), but you can't buy them to use in a circuit, and probably won't be able to anytime soon.